# Is it a Male or Female HDMI connection on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: hdmi

Is the HDMI connection on a Raspberry Pi male or female.
What I mean is, what type of HDMI cable plugs into the PI, is it male or female?

Comment: -1 for lack of effort a simple google search would have answered this question. I also assume that you don't have a Pi in front of you, but  wherever, you ordered one from would likely have this information.

Answer (score 3):

The cable needs a male end. As you can see from the photo below:

[image: Pi2]

You don't mention which model Pi you have, but all Pi's except the Pi Zero and ZeroW, you need a standard HDMI connector. The Pi Zero's use a mini HDMI connector, as can be seen in this photo:

[image: Pi Zero]

Comment: Thank You Steve. Its a Pi3 so it will be a Standard HDMI then. Regards, Chris.